# Reproducción en segundo plano de app radio en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, stream

Hice una app para una radio online de un pueblo, me gustaria saber si me pueden ayudar para que se reproduzca en segundo plano cuando minimizo la aplicación gracias!

Les comparto código:

```
package com.example.emanuel.onlineradio;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button b_play;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;

//String stream = "http://198.211.113.185:8500/12";
String stream = "http://usa2-vn.mixstream.net:8028";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);

    b_play.setEnabled(false);
    b_play.setText("LOADING");

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                if(started) {
                    started = false;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    b_play.setText("PLAY");
                }

                else {
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    b_play.setText("PAUSE");
                }
            }
    }
    );
}

    class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return prepared;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            b_play.setEnabled(true);
            b_play.setText("PLAY");
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(started){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(started){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(prepared){
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu método `onDestroy()` elimina el `MediaPlayer` cuando la aplicación se cierra, por lo que se dejará de escuchar música.

Para que siga reproduciéndose en segundo plano deberás quitar el código del método `onDestroy()`. Tu código está pensado para que se pause o pare al cerrar la app, y siga cuando se abra.

Si quitas tu código de los métodos `onResume`, `onDestroy` y `onPause`debería funcionar.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha servido :D

Comment: @EmanuelCortez si te ha servido la respuesta de cnbandicoot por favor marca su respuesta como aceptada

Comment: el código funciona bien , pero me gustaría saber como hago para que la pre-carga "mediaPlayer.prepare();" se haga después de darle play y no antes