# como creo un listener para las llamadas entrantes?

Tags: procesos-en-segundo-plano, mediaplayer

tengo un activity que usa la clase media MediaPlayer, y necesito que al quedar en segundo plano se siga escuchando, pero que cuando entre un llamada al celular se detenga...

ya probé sobreescribir el metodo onPause(), onResume(), pero siempre que pasaba a segundo plano se detenpia mi reproductor, en realidad lo que deseo es que solo cuando entre una llamada se detenga el reproductor.

agradezco su amable ayuda.`

```js
package com.example.especialista.reproductor;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        MediaPlayer mp;
        crearReproductor();
    }


    public void onClickBtnPlay(View view) {

           mp.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onClickBtnStop(View view) {

         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
         crearReproductor();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    public  void crearReproductor(){
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.piano3);

    }
}
```

`

Comment: fiajte si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51297/reproducci%C3%B3n-en-segundo-plano-de-app-radio-en-android , aparte de esto por favor podrias agregar tu codigo , magicamente no podemos adivinar que tienes implementado y que es lo que te falte

Comment: lo que busco es que en segundo plano siga funcionando el reproductor, solo deseo que se detenga cuando entre una llamada.